# Machine learning on Spark via Mobius

Tags: c#, apache-spark

Mobius is the c# binding for apache spark. I wanted to know if MLlib and graphx can also be used via C#. As in can machine learning and graph processing jobs be made for apache spark via C#.

Answer (score 0):

If your spark driver is working over a Linux plateform, i suggest that you better better use LIVY. In fact, LIVY is Apache REST API, that gathers all the functionalities offered by all Spark api (Pyspark, scala, java ..). you can use LIVY to submit job on spark using pyspark snippets. I this seems to be a good solution for you, at least you don't have to ask each time which is working on mobius or not.